# How can I Insert Carriage Return in Crystal Report formula?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, string-formatting

I want to split my formula in Crystal Report to two lines, I think carriage return will do the trick, but how can I insert it in my formula?

Assuming that my formula is :

"Date : CurrentDateTime " & {CarriageReturn} & "User : Mr Smith"

Answer (score 6):

```
"Date : CurrentDateTime " & CHR(13) & "User : Mr Smith"
```

Make sure and set the formula as can grow after placing on the report canvas

Comment: `Make Sure` means you need to check the can grow option for the formula because you are adding the new line else you will be able to see only first line not other